# visual studio 2010 release can't find dll

Tags: debugging, dll, release, exe

I've build a project with opencv, when I share my .exe on other pc they can't find some dlls, this happens in release and debug mode, I searched on the web and I know I must configure the properties of the project, I tried configure MFC but with all the configuration the problem persist.
thank you!

Comment: what dlls are missing? Runtime libraries? without knowing that, we can't help you.

Comment: i suppose this is the first dll that miss : opencv_core240.dll

Answer (score 0):

Are they SystemFramework libraries? Or are they libraries that your app specifically uses, ones that you have imported into the project?

If they are your custom/imported libraries, make sure you copy them to output, and send them with the exe. The point of an installer is to bring the client your executable will of the the files it need to reference, compiled into a single file.

Comment: the first that miss is opencv_core240.dll i must link it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the runtime librarie of opencv are missing. I'm not familiar with opencv, but VS provides a way to find all dependencies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293568.aspx. You can build an installation package for your application.

Another way to find all dependencies is using depends.exe, details are in:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235265.aspx